# Keyboard settings doesnt work

Tags: 14.04, keyboard

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04, and everything was fine for the first couple of days. Then suddenly my keyboard setting had changed to english from danish, but when I went to keyboard settings, it was actually set to danish. I managed to fix it by removing the option english so only danish was left. And that worked for a couple of days as well. Now it is back to english again even though it still says that it is set to danish...

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: When you say the keyboard is English, where is that? In the terminal or in other programs or everywhere?

Comment: It's everywhere..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix it by using the command

> setxkbmap dk

However, the problem still appears from time to time, but the above command always works. I still think its weird that it randomly resets the language sometimes, so if anyone has a permanent solution to this, please tell.